# ¿Se puede cambiar de consola en Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Mi duda es si se puede utilizar la consola del sistema operativo (por ej, la "cmd" de Windows, o "terminal" en Linux) para ver las salidas de los programas en Eclipse, en ves de la consola proporcionada por Eclipse.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Sí se puede realizar pero a través de un plugin adicional. No recuerdo el nombre.

Comment: Okas, muchas gracias Luiggi, voy a buscar al respecto a ver que encuentro.

Comment: Encontré https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/terminal-plug y https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es configurar un lanzador externo para cmd o terminal, para esto:

- Vas al menu **run->External Tools->External Tools Configurations**
- Una vez ahí creas un nuevo programa y llenas los datos que solicitan

Aquí tienes un tutorial más detallado.

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console.html

**EDITADO CON RESPUESTA ÚTIL**

@AugustoHerbel también, si lo que quieres es mostrar los resultados abriendo la consola, podrías hacerlo mediante código, aquí pongo un pequeño ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  try { 
    int a = 3, b = 2, suma = 0; 
    suma = a+b; 
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start echo suma: "+suma); 
  } catch (IOException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Perdon @juan1992, me parece que me exprese mal, mi idea era que la consola del SO no se ejecutara dentro de eclipse, sino que se mostrara como lo hace siempre (en Windows por ej., que salga la caja negra con los resultados de mi programa). No se si soy lo suficientemente claro al expresarme, decime si necesitas que me explique mejor.

Comment: @AugustoHerbel si lo que quieres es mostrar los resultados abriendo la consola, podrías hacerlo mediante código, aquí pongo un pequeño ejemplo: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   int a = 3, b = 2, suma = 0;
   suma = a+b;
   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start echo suma: "+suma);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }` Avísame si te funciona para  ponerlo como respuesta.

Comment: Te pongo el código que use para probar lo que me dijiste y el error que me sale:

`import java.io.IOException;

public class Main 
{ 
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  try 
  {
   int num = 4 / 0;
   num += num * 4;
   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start echo num: " + num);
  } 
  catch (ArithmeticException | IOException e) 
  {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
 }
}`
Salida (eclipse)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]

Comment: Perdon, esa división es "4 / 1", no "4 / 0". Arregle eso y funciona de 10, muchas gracias. De todas formas mi idea era que la consola del SO quede por defecto a la hora de ejecutar programas, puede ser posible eso? Es decir, que no tenga que agregar código a cada proyecto nuevo.

Comment: @AugustoHerbel Ya edite la respuesta, si te sirvió marcarla como solución a tu problema, así otros usuarios también la pueden hallar útil. Referente a tu pregunta si es posible hacerlo de forma predeterminada, solo se logra hacer mediante plugins como menciona Luiggi Mendoza, o creando un lanzador externo, pero eso no abre la consola en windows, sino solo crea un lanzador dentro del mismo eclipse.

Comment: Ya esta marcada, mil gracias por la ayuda. Me podrías decir como se hace para hacer el lanzador? y que significa crear un lanzador dentro de eclipse? Graciass